# Correct syntax to recall a self-invoking function

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have a self-envoking function, like so:

```
(function myFunc(){
    alert("do something cool");
})();
```

I'm attempting to get this to run again when the browser is resized. Therefore I attempted this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    myFunc();
});
```

The browser is reporting back that `myFunc` doesn't exist. I've tried reordering the above so that the resize function appears before, this still doesn't work.

Please can someone point out the (proabably painfully obvious) error in my ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you've used allows the name `myFunc` only to be seen inside the `myFunc` function itself. It is called a [named function expression](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#named-expr).

```
(function myFunc() {
    // myFunc can be seen and used here
})();

// but not here.
```

Instead, try;

```
function myFunc() {
    alert("do something cool");
}

myFunc();

$(window).resize(function () {
    myFunc();
});
```

Comment: Ah so I was coding it as an anonymous self executing function! Makes a whole lot of sense now.

Answer (score 1):

A function may reference itself via `arguments.callee`, however it must be done right.

```
window.onresize = arguments.callee;
```

This will work. However if you're a jQuery nut (note: [I am not](http://vanilla-js.com/)), you might be tempted to write this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {arguments.callee();});
```

This will fail horribly and cause an infinite loop, because at the point of being called `arguments.callee` references the resize function itself.

EDIT: Upon further consideration, it wouldn't cause an infinite loop. It would error out after a moment due to a stack overflow error. Should've realised that, considering where I'm posting :p